# What C# AES encryption options to use so result can be decrypted on a public web site?

Tags: c#, aes

I would like to encrypt a string using code similar to the below and be able to decrypt it using a publicly available website such as one of these (but am open to some other site out there as well):

http://aesencryption.net/

http://www.nakov.com/blog/2011/12/26/online-aes-encryptor-decryptor-javascript/

Here is the code I'm currently playing around with and trying on these sites, I haven't been able to find the options that will make this work. Any ideas?

```
        public class AES
        {
            private readonly int _saltSize = 32;

            public string Encrypt(string plainText, string key)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(plainText))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
                }

                using (var keyDerivationFunction = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, _saltSize))
                {
                    byte[] saltBytes = keyDerivationFunction.Salt;
                    byte[] keyBytes = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(32);
                    byte[] ivBytes = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(16);

                    using (var aesManaged = new AesManaged())
                    {
                        aesManaged.KeySize = 256;

                        using (var encryptor = aesManaged.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, ivBytes))
                        {
                            MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
                            CryptoStream cryptoStream = null;

                            return WriteMemoryStream(plainText, ref saltBytes, encryptor, ref memoryStream, ref cryptoStream);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            public string Decrypt(string ciphertext, string key)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ciphertext))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("ciphertext");
                }

                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
                }

                var allTheBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ciphertext);
                var saltBytes = allTheBytes.Take(_saltSize).ToArray();
                var ciphertextBytes = allTheBytes.Skip(_saltSize).Take(allTheBytes.Length - _saltSize).ToArray();

                using (var keyDerivationFunction = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, saltBytes))
                {
                    var keyBytes = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(32);
                    var ivBytes = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(16);

                    return DecryptWithAES(ciphertextBytes, keyBytes, ivBytes);
                }
            }

            private string WriteMemoryStream(string plainText, ref byte[] saltBytes, ICryptoTransform encryptor, ref MemoryStream memoryStream, ref CryptoStream cryptoStream)
            {
                try
                {
                    memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

                    try
                    {
                        cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);

                        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
                        {
                            streamWriter.Write(plainText);
                        }
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (cryptoStream != null)
                        {
                            cryptoStream.Dispose();
                        }
                    }

                    var cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    Array.Resize(ref saltBytes, saltBytes.Length + cipherTextBytes.Length);
                    Array.Copy(cipherTextBytes, 0, saltBytes, _saltSize, cipherTextBytes.Length);

                    return Convert.ToBase64String(saltBytes);
                }
                finally
                {
                    if (memoryStream != null)
                    {
                        memoryStream.Dispose();
                    }
                }
            }

            private static string DecryptWithAES(byte[] ciphertextBytes, byte[] keyBytes, byte[] ivBytes)
            {
                using (var aesManaged = new AesManaged())
                {
                    using (var decryptor = aesManaged.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, ivBytes))
                    {
                        MemoryStream memoryStream = null;
                        CryptoStream cryptoStream = null;
                        StreamReader streamReader = null;

                        try
                        {
                            memoryStream = new MemoryStream(ciphertextBytes);
                            cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);
                            streamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream);

                            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            if (memoryStream != null)
                            {
                                memoryStream.Dispose();
                                memoryStream = null;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: cryptology isnt my strongest side, but isnt the salt size supposed to match in both encryption/decryption? i suggest you figure out what salt is being used on those websites and adjust your code accordingly.

Comment: does it work?  whats is the question?

Comment: @Plutonix: No, it doesn't work. The question is the first sentence.

Comment: @Banana: If you or anyone knows of a web site where the parameters are provided so I could match them up, that would be a good first step...

Comment: unfortunately i dont, but the sizes will most likely be provided in multiples of 2, so you can try 8/16/32/etc till you get the right ones. also, you could always upload your own decryption website on some free server...

Comment: I'm trying to avoid that if possible but that is my fallback plan if nobody knows of an existing one or some method to get it to match up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code works for encrypting the string "this is a test" with a key of "abcdefghijklmnop" and then decrypting at the site http://aesencryption.net/

```
    static void test()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToBase64String(EncryptStringToBytes("this is a test", System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("abcdefghijklmnop"))));
    }

    static byte[] EncryptStringToBytes(string plainText, byte[] key)
    {
        if (plainText == null || plainText.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (key == null || key.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

        byte[] encrypted;
        using (var rijAlg = new RijndaelManaged())
        {
            rijAlg.BlockSize = 256;
            rijAlg.Key = key;
            rijAlg.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            rijAlg.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;
            rijAlg.IV = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 };

            ICryptoTransform encryptor = rijAlg.CreateEncryptor(rijAlg.Key, rijAlg.IV);
            using (var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream())
            using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
                    swEncrypt.Write(plainText);
                encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();
            }
        }
        return encrypted;
    }
```